# CPU Usage Server and Monitoring info

Tags: linux, bash, sh, cpu, monitoring

I need to check, using a shell script, possibly without installing any particular package (OS:Linux Suse 12), the **total CPU % usage** in order to monitor the level without pass the critical threshold.

It is a Huge server with 2x E5-2667 v4 8/core.

[image]

Looking over the questions I found something and I tried it:

```
1-top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | \sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | \awk '{print 100 - $1"%"}'

2-CPU_LOAD=$(sar -P ALL 1 2 |grep 'Average.*all' |awk -F" " '{print 100.0 -$NF}')
```

I also tried to do 100-idle from iostat

1. Is that really correct on a multi cpu/multi core system?
2. Is correct calculate the cpu total usage by using the cpu load from the uptime?

Using the code i got an avg of single core, While i need a result of a total CPU used in %
Regards,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better implementing the solution completely in awk:

```
top -bn1 | awk -F, '/id/ { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( $i ~ /[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]][[:blank:]]+id/ ) { split($i,arry," ");print arry[1]" - idle" }'
```

Take the output from top and then check for any output containing id. If the condition is met, take each comma delimited piece of data on the line and pattern match against 2 numbers, a decimal and then one or more numbers, a blank and then id. If this is the case, split the variable based on a blank space into an array and print the first element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyway, There is something wrong on that snippet, can't figure what it is. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the closing single quote at the end. Do you have a percent in the idle output? i.e. 97.7% id,?

Comment: Thanks. I think some closing braket at the end, should be:                                           

`top -bn1 | awk -F, '/id/ { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( $i ~ /[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]][[:blank:]]+id/ ) { split($i,arry," ");print arry[1] }}}' `

This will return me an idle % i guess.

So it is actualy correct do 100-idle output to see the total usage of the cpu?

Comment: Yeah, just amend the final print statement, as I have just now.

Comment: If you are looking for a measure across multiple processors/cores then as others have pointed out, the load will be a better measure.

Comment: I Accept this answer, anyway could you explain better to me what that code does?

Comment: I've explained it in the answer .What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: You take the answer from top.
output sample : %Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st

For any of this number you are collecting ildle-0.3 for example ? and then  sum all over the result?

Comment: We concentrate on the output of top with a line that has "id" in it, we then go through each bit of the line separated by , and check that bit of data that pattern matches a number with decimal followed by id. We then split just to get the number.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get any detailed stats you might also use `perf`.
In this example you may see the number of all CPU cycles during 1 second:

```
-bash-4.1# perf stat -a sleep 1

Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

   4002.822144      task-clock (msec)         #    3.999 CPUs utilized            (100.00%)
         22809      context-switches          #    0.006 M/sec                    (100.00%)
          1332      cpu-migrations            #    0.333 K/sec                    (100.00%)
         23794      page-faults               #    0.006 M/sec                  
    5409531172      cycles                    #    1.351 GHz                      (100.00%)
<not supported>      stalled-cycles-frontend  
<not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
    3874289082      instructions              #    0.72  insns per cycle          (100.00%)
     715152901      branches                  #  178.662 M/sec                    (100.00%)
      20583742      branch-misses             #    2.88% of all branches        
   1.001065623 seconds time elapsed
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also check `uptime`.

Uptime  gives  a  one  line display of the following information.  The current time, how long the system has been running, how  many users are currently logged on, and the **system load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes.**

Comment: Hi gbajson, thanks for the answer. Uptime load does indicates how many processes are waiting to be executed? not the real amount of the % total CPU usage right?.